# JavaScript - Cannot read property 'top' of null

Tags: javascript, nullpointerexception

I have function that scrolls to a anchor position in a list

```
   function snapToAnchor(anchor) {
    $('#divProductScroll').scrollTop(0);
    var offset = $(anchor).offset().top - $('#divProductScroll').offset().top;
    $('#divProductScroll').scrollTop(offset);
    //$('#divProductScroll').animate({ scrollTop: offset }, 250);
}
```

but this is giving me error some times

saying **Cannot read property 'top' of null**

I am not so good with JavaScript

Can any one help with this issue?

**I found the Problem.**

---

This snapToAnchor function is in a dialog model, so second time when i hit this function, there is not list generated, that's why i have null value, so what i did is before firing this function, i recreate the modal and then step in to the function, now no scope of null.

Comment: I'm guessing you're not passing a legitimate tag name to the function in the `anchor` parameter.

Comment: one of those two .offset() calls is returning a null. Split up the substraction and assign each offset to a var, and see which one comes out null.

Comment: could learn how to use firebug, then put a break inside the function, so you can see what's in the variable `anchor`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The anchor variable does not contain a valid selector for you site. Calling `offset` on this will return `null`.

**Example**

```
var a = $('#non-existing-id'); //returns empty object
var b = a.offset(); // returns null
b.top; //throws a TypeError exception
```

You can simply debug your program by inserting `alert(anchor)` on line 3. This will show you the contents of the variable.

Answer (score 1):

if **anchor** has id of the DOM element - then correct way to use it with jQuery:

```
$('#' + anchor).offset()
```

otherwise you'll get a null (and error).

Answer (score 0):

```
$(anchor).offset().top
```

will usually output a string not a number... something like 100px.
you need to extract the number from the string.

```
var topoffset = $(anchor).offset().top;
topoffset = topoffset.split('px', 1);
```