# uncaught cannot read top of null

Tags: jquery

I've got some links as such:

```
 <ul class="vertlist">
    <li><a href="#personal" title="Go to Personal section." class="crumblink">Personal</a></li>
    <li><a href="#business" title="Go to Business section." class="crumblink">Business</a></li>
    <li><a href="#company" title="Go to Company section." class="crumblink">Company</a></li>
    <li><a href="#engineering" title="Go to Engineering section." class="crumblink">Engineering</a></li>
    <li><a href="#it" title="Go to IT section." class="crumblink">IT</a></li>
    <li><a href="#hr" title="Go to HR section." class="crumblink">HR</a></li>
  </ul>
```

And some jquery that is supposed to allow for some smooth navigation as such:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.crumblink').click(function () {
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top
                }, 500);
                return false;
            });
        })
```

The minute I click any of the links I get an uncaught exception regarding:

"Cannot read property top of null"

The anchor tag for example for personal is as such:

`<h2><a name="personal" id="myPersonal">Personal</a></h2>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to fetch the `href` property from your anchor, you're not doing it right (or perhaps I have yet to uncover the mysteries of jQuery):

```
scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top
```

It should be:

```
scrollTop: $(this.href).offset().top
```

If the value for `href` is an invalid selector, `offset()` will probably return `null`. This code will guard against that:

```
var elements = $(this.href);

if (elements && elements.length) {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: elements.offset().top
    }, 500);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The anchor variable does not contain a valid selector for you site. Calling offset on this will return **null**.

you are trying to access href that is not existed.

[see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7933582/javascript-cannot-read-property-top-of-null)